# Using typeof to check for function

Tags: javascript

I using `typeof` to identify the type of an element.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
alert("before = " + typeof test);
function test(i) {}
alert("after = " + typeof test);
</script>
```

In output I am seeing as:

```
before = function
after = function
```

When the page loads then the function is not yet defined, then the first alert should say `undefined`. So why it says `function` in my output?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that a function is hoisted. So it's valid to have:

```js
func()
function func (){
alert('alert')
}
```

Comment: We really don't need *yet another answer* to this question. (And the word you wanted was "hoisted," not "scoped.")

Comment: Oh. Thnaks for correction.